# Spring-Hibernate Transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions

I am using Spring 1.2.9 and Hibernate 3.3.1. I am running into a weird transaction problem. My transaction settings in spring are like this

```
<property name="writeInfo*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly</property>
<property name="getFacilities*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly</property>
```

The writeInfo method is more or like a service layer which may use other DAOs to query for objects, iterate through them, call other non-data helper methods (but may pass the data objects). The getFacilities is a DAO method that can be called by any method that requires access to database objects.

My code flow is, writeInfo is called with a bunch of object ids, for which data has to be exported to a text file. writeInfo method queries for these objects by passing them to getFacilities DAO method (there is DAO proxy injected into the proxy containing the writeInfo method). Once getFacilities returns the collection of objects, the writeInfo method calls other helper methods within the same class that iterates through these objects and their children objects and writes to a string buffer.

The problem is that when I debug the transaction statements on the spring-hibernate transaction manager, I see that a transaction is being created for writeInfo method and again a new transaction is created for getFacilities method even though the getFacilities method is being called from within writeInfo method. The bigger problem being that when the objects are returned from getFacilities method and passed on to other helper methods from writeInfo, any access to child objects (collections within the main objects) result in LazyIntialization exceptions because of Session Closed.

Shouldn't the transaction started by the writeInfo method be available till the end of the method? Why is the getFacilities method creating a new transaction and closing the session after transaction when it returns the objects? Is this a bug in this particular version of Spring or am I doing something wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would need to see more of the spring config, and maybe Java samples.BTW - spring 1.2.9? why so old?